# From built-in module to loadable module, /etc/module

Tags: module, linux-kernel, kernel, driver

I am trying to build a module that, I think, is essential to my system. This is the USB driver. If the module is not present, I fear that my mouse and keyboard will not be functionnal anymore.

Thereby, I would like to convert this built in module to a loadable module AND automatically load this module at boot. I know I have to compile a new kernel, set the option of my module to "m" with the "make menuconfig" command to make it loadable, but once done, the module will not be loaded at boot. So I would like to add the module to the /etc/module file to load it at boot.

If you know how to do, or a more handy metod to be able to test my driver while I am working on it, it would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

default loading of modules can be specified using modprobe.conf or modprobe.d. check this link: https://linux.die.net/man/5/modprobe.conf

Comment: In fact, the file /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf is a link to the file /etc/module. I have tried to modify this file and it perfectly works. What I would like to do is knowing what to do in order to have this file modified AFTER the kernel compilation.

For example, I modify a (I do not know which) file in the kernel sources, I compile my kernel, and then, when I boot for the first time, the module I wanted to load is already loaded because the /etc/odprobe.d/modprobe.conf has been modified.